# Classes, Namespacing, bin/console commands

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony, crud

I just started with Symfony framework this afternoon. I moved onto "CRUD" and was following a tutorial to use the tools built in to generate the CRUD. However, using the default commands, I am getting errors.

```
Attempted to load class "Task" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
500 Internal Server Error - ClassNotFoundException
```

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLQIEbOKvrc&t=304s) is the video I was following.

1. I started with a blank installation of Symfony.
2. Connected the database.
3. Ran `php bin/console generate:doctrine:entity`, wrote
   AppBundle:Tasks, and pressed enter through all options defaults to
   create a simple name and notes field.
4. Ran `php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud` wrote AppBundle:Tasks, and pressed enter through all option defaults but selecting yes for generating all the CRUD commands
5. Ran `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`
6. Ran `php bin/console cache:clear`
7. Go to `//localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/tasks` and I'm brought to the list, works fine.
8. But if I go to `localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/tasks/new` or click the generated button, I get the error mentioned above.

The error message is greek to me, despite its best attempts to be polite. I can see there is a Tasks.php file under Entity and it defines the class "Tasks" and the TasksController is set to `use AppBundle\Entity\Tasks` so I have no idea why it is not working with my limited understanding of all this.

I'm trying to build a fairly simple Task Management app but am completely new to Symfony and do not have a solid background in PHP to begin with. Could someone please explain where in the process I may have gone awry?

Comment: The error message is looking for a class called Task not Tasks.  So check your controller for a new Task() line.  And yes, once you have things working then rename Tasks to Task and save yourself some trouble.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks. That was it! I had a plural class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check:

- The name of the file `Task.php` is the same than the class name `class Task`. Note: a class should not be in plurial, so `Task` is right et `Tasks` is wrong
- You have a `use AppBundle\Entity\Task;` between your `Controller` namespace and class declaration

To avoid this error, you could use a PHP IDE like Phpstorm (or other), it display your statement in color when you forget to add a use statement.It also add it automatically :D

Comment: Thank you very much! Finally got a chance to look into this and mess with it and indeed that was the problem.

For future reference, is having "signular task" as opposed to "tasks" a forced PHP convention or a forced Symphony convention? Just curious to learn.

Comment: @chris98.5 Neither is forced.  Either will work.  Somewhere along the line you were inconsistent.